# HID IR Touch Screen Data Analyse

Tags: python, serial-port, usb, hid

I have this HID IR Touch Panel and Im using this panel in my project [https://www.amazon.com/GreenTouch-Infrared-Without-Interface-Free-Drive/dp/B078X8R9Z3?th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B078X8R9Z3) when I connect the this device touch anywhere and check the data with Busdog program I get below data. How can I analyse the this data ? Is that possible to solve ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0itF.png)

Comment: "*Is that possible to solve ?*" -- Reading the manual (aka RTM) is usually the first thing to try. Otherwise this is the wrong site for your vague questions.

Comment: there is no manuel. The prodcut owner dont share this dcuments I asked them